# SQL Server cursor - cannot assign variable properly

Tags: loops, variables, scope, cursor, sql-server-2016

I use SQL Server 2016. I need to move users from a legacy system to a new one. But before bringing all users from the legacy system, I need to check if they do not already exist in our new system. Such a determination is done based on comparison of users' email addresses in each of the system.

So if a user does not exist in the new system, I need to insert such a record into the new system from the legacy one. But if user does exist, I need to update some columns in the new system with data from the legacy one.

To accomplish it I'm using a cursor with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Also I need to log newly inserted and existing updated records in each cursor iteration. The problem is that my code does not differentiate new and existing records hence it inserts all user id in the Log table twice. One time in case the userID (@ContactID) IS NULL (not existing in the new system) and another when userID (@ContactID) IS NOT NULL - existing in the new system.

In my sample below I have 1 records that does not exists in the new system and 3 do match already. So in the IF (@CoantactID IS NULL) I meant to insert only that newly inserted into the MyDB.dbo.Contact table record and in the IF (@CoantactID IS NOT NULL) insert into the Log table only the tree records matched (existing) in the new system.

But the problem is that it inserts all four ContactIDs into the log table even in the this IF (@ContactID IS NULL) amd then again for in IF (@ContactID IS NOT NULL)

```
;USE [MyDB];
GO

-- exec dbo.sp_UserMigration_Users_Copy
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.sp_UserMigration_Users_Copy
GO

;USE [MyDB];
GO

CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.sp_UserMigration_Users_Copy
 @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
 --,@ContactID INT

AS 

DECLARE @Email nvarchar(100),
        @ContactID INT;
-- @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,

DECLARE @SysID INT
SET @SysId = 17511; -- system contactID

---- creating log table 
--CREATE TABLE #T 
--(
-- UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
-- Email NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
--);

SELECT * INTO #T 
FROM MyDB.dbo.User
WHERE UserID IN (   
                        '0604C514',
                        'C1FDAF34', 
                        '23BABE2D',
                        'EBA21D10'
                    ); 

IF NOT EXISTS (select * from MyDB.sys.tables where name = N'UserIDContactIDMigrationLog')

    CREATE TABLE MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
        (
            UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER /* CONSTRAINT [PK_UserIDContactIDMigrationLog_UserID] PRIMARY KEY */ NOT NULL,  -- somehow inserts duplicate UserIDs 
            ContactId INT /*UNIQUE CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_ContactId] */ NOT NULL,
            CreatedDt DATETIME2 NULL,
            UpdatedDt DATETIME2 NULL,
            UpdatedFlag BIT /*CONSTRAINT [DF_MigratedFlag] DEFAULT(0) */ NULL
        );

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Cursor: For all contacts to be migrated
-- -----------------------------------------------------
IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','user_cursor')) >= -1
 BEGIN
  IF (SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','user_cursor')) > -1
   BEGIN
    CLOSE user_cursor
   END
 DEALLOCATE user_cursor
END

DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR
    FOR 
        SELECT a.UserID, LTRIM(RTRIM(a.Email)) AS Email
        FROM #T a WITH (NOLOCK)      
        --WHERE a.UserID = @UserID

-- begin cursor loop
OPEN user_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @UserID, @Email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @ContactID = (
        SELECT c.ContactId
        FROM MyDB.dbo.Contact c 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Login l ON c.ContactId = l.ContactId  
        WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(c.ContactEmailTx)) = @Email 
                OR LTRIM(RTRIM(l.ContactLoginNameTx)) = @Email 
                --OR l.ContactLoginNameTx LIKE @Email+'%'  -- this concept does not work in case of leading space at the ContactLoginNameTx so need to use the code below 
                OR SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(l.ContactLoginNameTx)), -1, CHARINDEX('.INACTIVE.', l.ContactLoginNameTx)) = @Email)
        AND (c.ContactEmailTx != '' OR c.ContactEmailTx IS NOT NULL OR l.ContactLoginNameTx != '' OR l.ContactLoginNameTx IS NOT NULL)
                        )

-- check if a contact is new
    IF (@ContactID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- MyDB.dbo.Contact
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Contact]
            (   
                [ContactFirstNameTx],
                [ContactLastNameTx],
                [ContactEmailTx],
                [ContactTitleTx],
                [ContactCreateDt],
                [ContactCreateByID],
                [ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
            )
        SELECT 
                [FirstName],
                [LastName],
                [Email],
                [Title],
                --[AccountId],
                [UserCreatedDate],
                @SysId AS [ContactCreateByID],  -- as as flag for import [ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
                -10 AS [ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
        FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE UserID = @UserID 

        SET @ContactID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
--   select * from  [MyDB].[dbo].[Contact] where contactid in ( 1051364, 466440, 560466, 618576)
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    --MyDB.dbo.Login
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Login]          
    (   
        ContactID,
        [ContactLoginNameTx], -- V.C. this is email. the field is has a unique constraint
        [ContactLoginActiveIn],
        [ContactLoginCreateDt],
        [ContactLoginCreateByID],
        [ContactLoginCreateLoginTypeID],
        [ContactLoginPasswordLastChangeDt],
        [ContactLoginLastLoginDt],
        [ContactLoginPasswordExclusionIn] -- this is not nullable and BIT
    )
    SELECT 
        @ContactID AS ContactID,
        [Email],
        CASE WHEN [UserStatusID] IN (1, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [ContactLoginActiveIn], -- v.c. in Onvia 1 is Active, 2 - Inactive, 3 - Invited, 4 - Inactive By System, 5 - Pending Registration
        [UserCreatedDate],
        @SysId AS ContactLoginCreateByID,  -- as as flag for Onvia import[ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
        -10 AS [ContactLoginCreateLoginTypeID],
        [UserLastPasswordChangedDate],
        [UserLastLoginDate],
        0 as ContactLoginPasswordExclusionIn -- this is not nullable and BIT
    FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE UserID = @UserID
    AND NOT EXISTS (select * from MyDB.dbo.Login z where z.ContactID = @ContactID)

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Activate any inactive users 
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    IF EXISTS (select * from MyDB.dbo.Login where ContactLoginActiveIn = 0 and ContactID = @ContactID)
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from MyDB.dbo.Login where ContactLoginActiveIn = 1 and ContactID = @ContactID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [MyDB].[dbo].[Login]
        SET ContactLoginNameTx = @Email,
            ContactLoginActiveIn = (select case when [UserStatusID] IN (1, 3) then 1 else 0 end 
                                        from #T o where o.UserID = @UserID) 
        WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
    END

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    --MyDB.dbo.ContactPhoneNumber
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[PhoneNumber]        
    (   
        ContactID,
        PhoneNumberTypeID,
        ContactPhoneNumberValueTx 
    )

    SELECT 
        @ContactID AS ContactID,
        1 AS PhoneNumberTypeID,
        ISNULL([PhoneNumber1],'') AS ContactPhoneNumberValueTx
    FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE o.UserID = @UserID 
    AND NOT EXISTS (select * from [MyDB].[dbo].[PhoneNumber] z where z.ContactID = @ContactID);

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    --MyDB.dbo.ContactOrg
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Org]      
    (   
        ContactID,
        OrgID
    )
    SELECT 
        @ContactID AS ContactID,
        b.OrgID AS OrgID
    FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN ImportQueue.dbo.OnviaAccountIDOrgIDMigrationLog b WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.AccountId = b.OnviaAccountID
    WHERE o.UserID = @UserID 
    AND NOT EXISTS (select * from [MyDB].[dbo].[Org] z where z.ContactID = @ContactID);

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    ---- MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
    ---- log output for new users
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
    (
        UserID,
        ContactId,
        CreatedDt,
        UpdatedFlag
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        @UserID,
        @ContactID,
        GETDATE(),
        0 
    )

        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        --  EXISTING MATCHED USERS
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
            -- check if a contact is existing
    IF (@ContactID IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- MyDB.dbo.Contact
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        UPDATE MyDB.dbo.Contact
        SET ContactFirstNameTx =
                CASE 
                    WHEN ContactFirstNameTx NOT IN ('', NULL) THEN c.FirstName
                    ELSE ContactFirstNameTx
                END,
            ContactLastNameTx = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN ContactLastNameTx IN ('', NULL) THEN c.LastName
                    ELSE ContactLastNameTx
                END,
            ContactEmailTx = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN ContactEmailTx IN ('', NULL) THEN c.Email
                    ELSE ContactEmailTx
                END,
            ContactTitleTx =
                CASE 
                    WHEN ContactTitleTx IN ('', NULL) THEN c.Title
                    ELSE ContactTitleTx
                END,
            [ContactCreateDt] =
                CASE 
                    WHEN ContactCreateDt IN ('', NULL) THEN c.UserCreatedDate
                    ELSE ContactCreateDt
                END,
            [ContactModifyByID] = @SysId,
            [ContactModifyLoginTypeID] = - 10

        FROM #T c
            WHERE UserID = @UserID 
            AND ContactID = @ContactID;
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    ---- MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
    ---- log output for existing matched users
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

            INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog 
             (
                 UserID,
                 ContactId,
                 UpdatedDt,
                 UpdatedFlag
             )

            VALUES 
             (
                @UserID,
                @ContactID,
                GETDATE(),
                1 
             );

        FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @UserID, @Email

        -- end cursor loop

    END
END

CLOSE user_cursor
        DEALLOCATE user_cursor

GO
```

Comment: Post sample data, please, along with your current code and the results you get - also known as a  [mcve].  You may not need to use a cursor here, either - you're not married to that approach, I hope?

Comment: In my sample I have 1 records that does not exists in the new system and 3 do match. So in the IF (@CoantactID IS NULL) I meant to insert only that newly inserted into the MyDB.dbo.Contact table record and in the IF (@CoantactID IS NOT NULL)  insert into the Log table only the tree records matched (existing) in the new system.

Comment: But the problem is that it inserts all four ContactIDs into the log table even in the this IF (@ContactID IS NULL) amd then again for in IF (@ContactID IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You might want to take a peek here too since you are using nolock against your temp table. It doesn't actually do anything more than cause you to type more. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/nolock-temp-tables/

Comment: The "nolock" on the temp table is just a copy paste issue. In real situation I use a physical table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Cursors try the below code.

```
- exec dbo.sp_UserMigration_Users_Copy
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.sp_UserMigration_Users_Copy
    GO

    ;USE [MyDB];
    GO

    CREATE  PROCEDURE dbo.sp_UserMigration_Users_Copy
     @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL
     --,@ContactID INT

    AS 

    DECLARE @Email nvarchar(100),
            @ContactID INT;


    DECLARE @SysID INT
    SET @SysId = 17511; 

    CREATE TABLE #T 
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     UserID NVARCHAR(50)NOT NULL,
     Email NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
    );
    INSERT INTO #T 
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyDB.dbo.User
    WHERE UserID IN (   
                            '0604C514',
                            'C1FDAF34', 
                            '23BABE2D',
                            'EBA21D10'
                        ); 

    IF NOT EXISTS (select * from MyDB.sys.tables where name = N'UserIDContactIDMigrationLog')

        CREATE TABLE MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
            (
                UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER /* CONSTRAINT [PK_UserIDContactIDMigrationLog_UserID] PRIMARY KEY */ NOT NULL,  -- somehow inserts duplicate UserIDs 
                ContactId INT /*UNIQUE CONSTRAINT [UNIQUE_ContactId] */ NOT NULL,
                CreatedDt DATETIME2 NULL,
                UpdatedDt DATETIME2 NULL,
                UpdatedFlag BIT /*CONSTRAINT [DF_MigratedFlag] DEFAULT(0) */ NULL
            );


    DECLARE @COUNT INT 
    DECLARE @I INT = 1
    DECLARE @UserID NVARCHAR(50) ;
    DECLARE @Email NVARCHAR(50)
    SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM #T
    WHILE(@I <= @COUNT)

    BEGIN 
            SELECT @UserID = UserID, @Email= LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)) FROM #T WHERE ID = @I   


        SELECT @ContactID = (
            SELECT c.ContactId
            FROM MyDB.dbo.Contact c 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN MyDB.dbo.Login l ON c.ContactId = l.ContactId  
            WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(c.ContactEmailTx)) = @Email 
                    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(l.ContactLoginNameTx)) = @Email 
                    --OR l.ContactLoginNameTx LIKE @Email+'%'  -- this concept does not work in case of leading space at the ContactLoginNameTx so need to use the code below 
                    OR SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(l.ContactLoginNameTx)), -1, CHARINDEX('.INACTIVE.', l.ContactLoginNameTx)) = @Email)
            AND (c.ContactEmailTx != '' OR c.ContactEmailTx IS NOT NULL OR l.ContactLoginNameTx != '' OR l.ContactLoginNameTx IS NOT NULL)
                            )

    -- check if a contact is new
        IF (@ContactID IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            -- MyDB.dbo.Contact
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Contact]
                (   
                    [ContactFirstNameTx],
                    [ContactLastNameTx],
                    [ContactEmailTx],
                    [ContactTitleTx],
                    [ContactCreateDt],
                    [ContactCreateByID],
                    [ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
                )
            SELECT 
                    [FirstName],
                    [LastName],
                    [Email],
                    [Title],
                    --[AccountId],
                    [UserCreatedDate],
                    @SysId AS [ContactCreateByID],  -- as as flag for Onvia import[ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
                    -10 AS [ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
            FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE UserID = @UserID 

            SET @ContactID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END
    --   select * from  [MyDB].[dbo].[Contact] where contactid in ( 1051364, 466440, 560466, 618576)
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        --MyDB.dbo.Login
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Login]          
        (   
            ContactID,
            [ContactLoginNameTx], -- V.C. this is email. the field is has a unique constraint
            [ContactLoginActiveIn],
            [ContactLoginCreateDt],
            [ContactLoginCreateByID],
            [ContactLoginCreateLoginTypeID],
            [ContactLoginPasswordLastChangeDt],
            [ContactLoginLastLoginDt],
            [ContactLoginPasswordExclusionIn] -- this is not nullable and BIT
        )
        SELECT 
            @ContactID AS ContactID,
            [Email],
            CASE WHEN [UserStatusID] IN (1, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [ContactLoginActiveIn], -- v.c. in Onvia 1 is Active, 2 - Inactive, 3 - Invited, 4 - Inactive By System, 5 - Pending Registration
            [UserCreatedDate],
            @SysId AS ContactLoginCreateByID,  -- as as flag for Onvia import[ContactCreateLoginTypeID]
            -10 AS [ContactLoginCreateLoginTypeID],
            [UserLastPasswordChangedDate],
            [UserLastLoginDate],
            0 as ContactLoginPasswordExclusionIn -- this is not nullable and BIT
        FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE UserID = @UserID
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from MyDB.dbo.Login z where z.ContactID = @ContactID)

        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Activate any inactive users 
        -- -----------------------------------------------------

        IF EXISTS (select * from MyDB.dbo.Login where ContactLoginActiveIn = 0 and ContactID = @ContactID)
            AND NOT EXISTS (select * from MyDB.dbo.Login where ContactLoginActiveIn = 1 and ContactID = @ContactID)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [MyDB].[dbo].[Login]
            SET ContactLoginNameTx = @Email,
                ContactLoginActiveIn = (select case when [UserStatusID] IN (1, 3) then 1 else 0 end 
                                            from #T o where o.UserID = @UserID) 
            WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
        END

        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        --MyDB.dbo.ContactPhoneNumber
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[PhoneNumber]        
        (   
            ContactID,
            PhoneNumberTypeID,
            ContactPhoneNumberValueTx 
        )

        SELECT 
            @ContactID AS ContactID,
            1 AS PhoneNumberTypeID,
            ISNULL([PhoneNumber1],'') AS ContactPhoneNumberValueTx
        FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE o.UserID = @UserID 
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from [MyDB].[dbo].[PhoneNumber] z where z.ContactID = @ContactID);

        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        --MyDB.dbo.ContactOrg
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        INSERT INTO [MyDB].[dbo].[Org]      
        (   
            ContactID,
            OrgID
        )
        SELECT 
            @ContactID AS ContactID,
            b.OrgID AS OrgID
        FROM #T o WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN ImportQueue.dbo.OnviaAccountIDOrgIDMigrationLog b WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.AccountId = b.OnviaAccountID
        WHERE o.UserID = @UserID 
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from [MyDB].[dbo].[Org] z where z.ContactID = @ContactID);

        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        ---- MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
        ---- log output for new users
        -- -----------------------------------------------------

        INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
        (
            UserID,
            ContactId,
            CreatedDt,
            UpdatedFlag
        )
        VALUES 
        (
            @UserID,
            @ContactID,
            GETDATE(),
            0 
        )

            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            --  EXISTING MATCHED USERS
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
                -- check if a contact is existing
        IF (@ContactID IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            -- MyDB.dbo.Contact
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            UPDATE MyDB.dbo.Contact
            SET ContactFirstNameTx =
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ContactFirstNameTx NOT IN ('', NULL) THEN c.FirstName
                        ELSE ContactFirstNameTx
                    END,
                ContactLastNameTx = 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ContactLastNameTx IN ('', NULL) THEN c.LastName
                        ELSE ContactLastNameTx
                    END,
                ContactEmailTx = 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ContactEmailTx IN ('', NULL) THEN c.Email
                        ELSE ContactEmailTx
                    END,
                ContactTitleTx =
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ContactTitleTx IN ('', NULL) THEN c.Title
                        ELSE ContactTitleTx
                    END,
                [ContactCreateDt] =
                    CASE 
                        WHEN ContactCreateDt IN ('', NULL) THEN c.UserCreatedDate
                        ELSE ContactCreateDt
                    END,
                [ContactModifyByID] = @SysId,
                [ContactModifyLoginTypeID] = - 10

            FROM #T c
                WHERE UserID = @UserID 
                AND ContactID = @ContactID;
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        ---- MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog
        ---- log output for existing matched users
        -- -----------------------------------------------------

                INSERT INTO MyDB.dbo.UserIDContactIDMigrationLog 
                 (
                     UserID,
                     ContactId,
                     UpdatedDt,
                     UpdatedFlag
                 )

                VALUES 
                 (
                    @UserID,
                    @ContactID,
                    GETDATE(),
                    1 
                 );




        END
 SET @I = @I+1;
    END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm not sure where the "ID" column is coming from? SELECT @UserID = UserID, @Email= LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)) FROM #T WHERE ID = I. The only identity column in the #T is the UserID

Comment: ID column is there in the #t table . It is an identity column.

Comment: So I added a new column to my #T table. But the SELECT @UserID = OnviaUserID, @Email= LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)) FROM #T WHERE ID = I  is hanging

Comment: If you execute everything including this code and above (but not below) you will see that its hanging BEGIND     SELECT @UserID = OnviaUserID, @Email= LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)) FROM #T WHERE ID = I      END

Comment: that means @I is not getting incremented.

Comment: And even If I run the procedure as you suggested it throws me an error saying that NULL value cannot be inserted into the USerID column in the log table. Basically is does not assign a value to a variable.

Comment: I added the ID field as follows: ALTER TABLE MYDB.dbo.User
ADD ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL

Comment: Can you try now. why do you need to add ID column in the User table. that will be there only in the #t table.

Comment: i already answered that (see comment #1). I did not have such a column. but you added it in your code

Comment: In any case I already have a temp table with the ID column that is coming from the source table ( MYDB.dbo.User ) as I do not create a #T explicitly but rather SELECT * INTO #T FROM MYDB.dbo.User. But as I said it's not assigning the UserID to the @UserID

Comment: My problem was that when I tested I used just a subset of data so in that subset ID column values were not subsequent and did not start with  1. Thanks for your help Sujatha.